# Out Of Range Exception 2D Array To List Of Type Int

Tags: c#, arrays

Why do I get an Out of Range Exception here?

The method takes `int[][] numbers` as a Parameter.

My Code:

```
 List<int> myList = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
     {
       for (int z = 0; z < numbers.GetUpperBound(1); z++)
           {
                myList.Add(intervals[i][z]);
           }
      }
```

I tried to Google it, but I don't have any glue.

Comment: `int[][]` is **jagged array** while your code is for `int[,]`

Comment: `int[,]` and `int[][]` are different.. Which does your function take as a parameter?

Comment: @IvanStoev ok ty, how can I Loop that jagged Array?

Comment: @Blorgbeard it takes 'int[][]'

Comment: for (int z = 0; z < numbers[i].Length; z++), as it's a jagged array, each element on the first level can have different inner sizes.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) for (int z = 0; z < numbers[i].Length; z++)`

Comment: Can anybody tell me why you are all giving the correct answer just in comments?

Comment: @IvanStoev ty it is working, I just coded something in Java for University and got confused now that I Need to do something in c#. If you write an answer I can mark it as the solution

Comment: @Aconcagua Because the question is pretty basic. No one respecting himself will post an answer and earn easy rep points with such question.

Comment: @IvanStoev In this case should I delete the question?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann I'm glad that the problem has been solved, what you will do with your question is up to you :) If you wish, you can post self answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev I do not see any problem if you earned points this way I'd see it dishonourable if some 'stealed' the points if posting an answer from your comments... You should see it from another point: I have profited already very much from this site - and in return, I'm trying to contribute myself, so I'm looking for unanswered questions to help people - just to find that they actually have been answered, but only in comments...

Comment: @Aconcagua I see your point, and it sounds reasonable. But it's a personal decision whether to answer in comments instead of posting a real answer, so if someone else decide to actually post an answer, I would not call it stealing because we had that chance and decided to not take that path. So we leave that choice for the others, as well as to OP to either delete the question or post self answer based on comments.

Comment: @Aconcagua there's some [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) on meta about the answers-in-comments phenomena. (And I agree with Ivan, when I answer in comments, I am fine with people posting answers referencing my lazy answer-comments - I would have answered myself if I wanted the points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is a jagged Array and so the code in the question isn't working. 
The way I'm Looping through the Array now is looking like this in  code:

```
 List<int> myList = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < intervals[i].Length; z++)
            {

                myList.Add(intervals[i][z]);

            }
        }
```